# Select the top points of each category in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table in SQLite:

```
category  | userId | points
----------|--------|---------
        25|     522|      380
        25|     487|      350
        25|     142|      100
        25|     385|      500
        26|     521|      300
        26|     524|      100
        26|     366|      880
        43|     123|      310
        43|     587|      340
        43|     935|       90
        43|     625|       85
```

I want to select the TOPs points of each category and have already tried in several ways without success.

For example:

```
Select distinct (category), userId, points
from RecordPoints order by category, points DESC
```

Expected outcome:

```
category  | userId | points
----------|--------|---------
        25|     385|      500
        26|     366|      880
        43|     587|      340
```

But the query result is not as expected as above.

Comment: What if two users have same max points in the same category?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the top value in each category, then you can use `where` and a correlated subquery:

```
select rp.*
from RecordPoints rp
where rp.points = (select max(rp2.points)
                   from RecordPoints rp
                   where rp2.category = rp.category
                  );
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can use MAX() to select an entire row from a group:

```
SELECT category, userId, max(points)
FROM RecordPoints
GROUP BY category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT rp.*
FROM RecordPoints rp
WHERE rp.points = (SELECT MAX(rps.points)
  FROM RecordPoints rps
  WHERE rps.category = rp.category);
```

OR

```
SELECT rp.*
FROM RecordPoints rp
JOIN (SELECT rps.category, MAX(rps.points) points
FROM RecordPoints rps GROUP BY rps.category) AS rp1 
ON (rp.category =   rp1.category AND rp.points = rp1.points);
```

Comment: Does SQL lite allow you to ignore userid in the group by?  if so does it know to return the user associated to the max user? or is it indeterminate like mySQL?

Comment: i apologise for that, it will not return the userId associated with max user, this is working fine < SELECT rp.*
FROM RecordPoints rp
WHERE rp.points = (SELECT MAX(rps.points)
                   FROM RecordPoints rps
                   WHERE rps.category = rp.category
                  ); >

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks for all, I use max and group by, problem is solved :D